# Merging a List of 2 Hibernate SQL-Queries

Tags: sql, list, hibernate, merge

i got 2 large SQL Querys with multiple joins and im trying to merge them into  a single list and cast it to the DAO class, but without success. Heres a simple example of my queries :

```
String sql_comp = "select cs.identification as id from code_system"; 
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(sql_comp)
              .addScalar("id", StandardBasicTypes.LONG) 
              .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FHIR_Parameters.class));
List list = q.list(); 

String sql_comp2 = "select vs.identification as id_2 from value_set"; 
Query q2 = session.createSQLQuery(sql_comp2)
              .addScalar("id_2", StandardBasicTypes.LONG) 
              .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FHIR_Parameters.class));
List list_2 = q2.list();
```

I have already tried various methods and have promised me the most success by the following method:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
result.addAll(list);
result.addAll(list_2);
fhir_codesystem = (FHIR_Parameters) result.get(0);
```

But the final cast always contains only the first list.

Someone an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks so far.

**Update #1:**

Ok thank you, have realized that my approach was stupid (i wanted to merge the elements, not the lists...) and has solved it wie a getter/setter as follows:

```
FHIR_Parameters fhir_codesystem_2 = (FHIR_Parameters) list_2.get(0);
fhir_codesystem.setVs_Id(fhir_codesystem_2.getVs_Id());
```

My question is still, whether there are not better solutions? So that I can put the new element over the old one and just fill the empty attributes?

Comment: are you sure that the 2 list are not empty ? list.size(), list_2.size() and result.size() returns what ?

Comment: yes, list 1 got a size of 21, list 2 of 22. It really depends on the sequence. When i add "list" first its parsing the items of "list", when i add "list_2" first its parsing the items of "list_2"

Comment: why this : fhir_codesystem = (FHIR_Parameters) result.get(0);  ?? you need a list not an element ? because result.get(0) return just the first element of the result list

Answer (score 1):

You are actually describing expected behavior.  Lists are ordered, so by adding "list" to result first, then items from "list" will always be first. As you are inspecting result.get(0); - this will ALWAYS be the first item from which ever list you added first.

You mention you want a merged list so you should be returning List from your query method - not a single FHIR_Parameters entity.

EDIT in response to edit!

A LinkedHashmap would help you out here (it preserves order if you need that). Apologies that I've not tested this before posting but perhaps this would help?

```
final Map<Long, FHIR_Parameters> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (FHIR_Parameters fhir1 : list) {
    myMap.put(fhir.getId(), fhir);
}
for (FHIR_Parameters fhir2 : list) {
    if (myMap.containsKey(fhir2.getId()) {
         final FHIR_Parameters fhir1 = myMap.get(fhir2.getId);
         //// do somthing to fhir1 (perhaps update from fhir2?)
    } else {
         // do something else, if you want to merge then:
         myMap.put(fhir2.getId(), fhir);
    }
}
final List<FHIR_Parameters> mergedList() = new ArrayList<>();
for (Long id : myMap.keySet()) {
    merged.add(myMap.get(id));
}
```

Comment: You were right, I was on the wrong path and could solve my problem now. Im asking myself if there is a better solution, so I can put the new element over the old one and fill the empty attributes.

Comment: No worries - I've updated my answer in response to your edit, I think this is along the lines of what you need. And I just noticed you've already solved it (doh!) - but hope it helps anyway.